# React-Native firebase registration how can i take username

Tags: firebase, react-native

This is my register code;

```
onButtonClicked1() {
  this.setState({
    error: '',
    loading: true
  })
  const {username, password} = this.state;
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
  .then(this.onRegisterSuccess.bind(this))
  .catch(() => {
    this.setState({
      error : 'Not registered.',
      loading: false
    })
  });
}
```

How can i take the username ?
After take username, it's be able to be updated in settings page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` firebase method will return you an Object with this structure after the promise is resolved (this can change in the future):

```
{
  additionalUserInfo: Object,
  credential: null,
  operationType: "signIn",
  user: {
    displayName: string,
    email: string,
    emailVerified: string,
    uid: string,
    ...
  }
}
```

From there you can access all the available information. However, keep in mind that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is expecting `email` and `password`. So, if the `username` in your app is the email, all good. If not, you might not get the result you want.

**Example of using a function after the promise is resolved:**

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
  .then((res) => {
    callAnyFunctionYouWant(res.user.email) // or res.user.displayName
  })
  .catch(() => {
    ...
  });
```

**In case you DO want username**

In case you have a custom `username` you want to use, you need to create a profile for the user right after the `firebase.auth()` and grab it with a different query. That, you can not do with the example code you provided. It needs extra work.

Hope that clears things up.